# Quickly fitting many data sets to the same fit

Tags: fitting

I have say 10 sets of data, all of which I want to perform a linear fit to using `LinearModelFit[...]`. Is there a way I can fit multiple data sets quickly rather than writing out `LinearModelFit[DataSet1]`, `LinearModelFit[DataSet2]`,LinearModelFit[DataSet3] and so on. And then ideally extract put the fit results into a list -- something like `FitResults={m1,m2,m3...}`?

The most obvious way to me is a `Do[...]` but somehow this seems a bit crude...Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: `Table[]` and `Map[]` are good.

Comment: @J.M. Any change of a quick e.g? I tried `TableData = Table[{Data1,Data2,Data3},{i,1}]` and then `LinearModelFit[TableData,x,x]`...no joy!

Comment: Could've done `Table[LinearModelFit[(* stuff *)], {dat, {Data1, (* stuff *)}}]` and joy is more likely to be had.

Comment: @J.M. You were indeed correct. I received much joy. Thanks nice solution!